# Unity Default Shader Greyed Out

Tags: unity, shaders

I created a pland in Unity 3D and then tried to alter the material.  I looked at it's material component, but all the options are greyed out!  how do I fix this problem?

Comment: Did you try creating your own material, if the default material is not configured to your needs?

Comment: I tried to, but I can't remove the material already added.  I tried right clicking, but there is no "remove component" option.

Comment: You tried assigning your custom material in the plane's mesh renderer component's material field?

Comment: Thanks, That worked, I haven't had much experience with 3D in unity, mainly 2D.

Comment: Please work through some basic tutorials to make sure you understand the engine's fundamentals.